# Clover crashing when launching WPF through Excel-DNA

Tags: c#, wpf, crash, ribbon, excel-dna

Okay, so I realize this is a very specific issue, that nobody has probably encountered before. But someone might have an idea. Here goes:

I have [clover installed](http://ejie.me/) (tabs in explorer). I have created an Excel ribbon for an Excel addin, using Excel-DNA. In my ribbon I have a button that opens up a WPF window. That is, the method for the click-event contains something like the following two lines:

```
var window = new MyWindow();
window.ShowDialog();
```

When I fire up the addin and click the button, Clover crashes (if it is open). The error occurs when calling the `ShowDialog`-method. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? It might be a problem with Excel-DNA or it might be a problem with Clover. Or something else entirely. It crashes on both computers I have tried it on.

- I have tried opening my WPF-window from a simple console application. Clover doesn't crash.
- I have tried uninstalling Clover (which substitutes explorer) and clicking the button. Explorer doesn't crash.
- I recently switched to using Excel-DNA for my addin. Before that (when I was using the Visual Studio Excel AddIn) it didn't crash.

Anything else I should try?

I haven't created a MWE. But if anyone would like me to, I could do so quite quickly. Oh, and by the way, I'm running Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: You will need to get a crash dump to see where the problem is comming from.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Okay, so I tried that. But I don't know what to read from the dump-file. Exception Information and Error Information are empty. Exception Code is 0xC0000409. I have tried attaching it to Clover, and provoked the error again. What happens is that a window pops up saying "clover.exe has triggered a breakpoint". In the output it says "STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered". Does that give you any idea about what could be the error?

Comment: I experienced similar problems in a Windows Server 2008 environment, using ExcelDNA and WPF. See this ExcelDNA thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/rxSsk5Y_rG4 - the short term solution to my problem was to remove the WPF components, we have not yet worked to reinstate them.